# What is the best way to have multiple videos playing inside a view?

Tags: ios, video, uiview, avfoundation

I'd like to arrange multiple videos inside a view like so:

[image]

So multiple views inside a scroll view. I am currently using AVFoundation to add multiple AVPlayers to UIViews arranged on a UIScrollView. On each scroll, I manually pause and play videos which are visible to avoid playing videos which are not even shown.

The problem is that the CPU utilisation on an iPhone 6 is over 40%.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If this is static content, why can't you create one video with all these videos outside in possibly a video editor, that way you have to manage playing only one video? Please ignore if your content is dynamic.

Comment: @gurtej videos are loaded in dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UICollectionView` and create a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and add `AVPlayer` in custom cell, then play video in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and stop playback inside `didEndDisplaycell` delegate methods, as `UICollectionView` will reuse cells it will make your app more performant. Collection view are specifically created for this kind of requirement .